# MySQL datetime field query sort by hour:minute

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, mysqldatareader

I have a table like this:

```
id  date_time
1   2/11/2013 7:05
2   2/11/2013 7:00
3   2/12/2013 7:00
4   2/14/2013 7:00
5   2/16/2013 7:00
6   2/17/2013 7:00
7   2/12/2013 7:05
8   2/14/2013 7:05
9   2/15/2013 7:05
10  2/16/2013 7:05
11  2/17/2013 7:05
12  2/13/2013 7:00
13  2/15/2013 7:00
14  2/13/2013 7:05
```

I need it sorted by HOUR:MINUTE and than sorted by DATE so I get something like this on output:

```
2/11/2013 7:00
2/12/2013 7:00
2/13/2013 7:00
2/14/2013 7:00
2/15/2013 7:00
2/16/2013 7:00
2/17/2013 7:00
2/11/2013 7:05
2/12/2013 7:05
2/13/2013 7:05
2/14/2013 7:05
2/15/2013 7:05
2/16/2013 7:05
2/17/2013 7:05
```

Is there a way to sort output directly with MySQL?... I know to do it via PHP once I get the query results, but just wonder if MySQL can do something like that ?

I tried a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (date_time BETWEEN '$date_check_low' AND '$date_check_high') ORDER BY hour(date_time) ASC
```

but it produces weird results...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ORDER BY HOUR(date_time), MINUTE(date_time), date_time
```

or

```
ORDER BY TIME(date_time), date_time
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4adc3/1)

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE (date_time BETWEEN '$date_check_low' AND '$date_check_high')
ORDER BY time(date_time),
         date_time;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.   Injecting variables directly into the query may lead to vulnerabilities/instability.